# Perl : Error on compilation, libssl.so.4 Can not open shared object

Tags: linux, perl, centos

After compiling my code it is giving me the following error. I think it is giving me error on my `use DBD::mysql`. I have recently installed that module on server (Centos 5). I am not that much used to of centos.

```
Can't load '/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: libssl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.


 at test_db.pl line 6
Compilation failed in require at test_db.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test_db.pl line 6.
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove whatever you installed to get DBD::mysql, and install the `perl-DBD-MySQL` package from the CentOS base repository via yum.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,  The problem is that on server no internet , i have to download respected rpm file and copy over there and install it . So yum cant work . :(   Due to that lots of dependency were coming so might be due to my lazy attitude i have done something wrong ...

Comment: Ya i think but i am doing this first time so dont have any idea . Well i have installed 1.MySQL-client-5.1.56-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm 2.MySQL-server-5.1.56-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm 3. perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64.rpm 4. openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.x86_64.rpm ... RPMs ... Please help me out for this ,

Comment: @manishc: You could (ask someone to) roll out your own repository and keep it on the trusted network, syncing with the outside ones from time to time.